# C/Linux: Alternating between threads

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, synchronization

So I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#define nr_threads 3
sem_t semaphores[nr_threads];
typedef struct {
    int id;
    char *word;
}th_struct;

void *thread_function(void *arg)
{
    th_struct *th_data = (th_struct *) arg; 

    sem_wait(&semaphores[th_data->id]);
        printf("[thread#%d] %s\n", th_data->id, th_data->word);
    sem_post(&semaphores[th_data->id + 1]);
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pthread_t tid[nr_threads];
    th_struct th_data[nr_threads];

    for(int i = 0; i < nr_threads; i++){
        if (sem_init(&semaphores[i], 0, 1) != 0){
            perror("Could not init semaphore");
            return -1;
        }
    }

    sem_post(&semaphores[0]);

    for(int i = 0; i < nr_threads; i++){
        th_data[i].id = i;
        th_data[i].word = argv[i + 1];
        pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, thread_function, &th_data[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < nr_threads; i++){
        pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < nr_threads; i++)
        sem_destroy(&semaphores[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

I give from the command line 3 words, for example "one two three", and each thread prints one word, synchronized, so that the order will be always correct. 
 I'm new to threads and semaphores, and my brain is currently used to sem_wait(sem) and after sem_post(sem), where sem is the same semaphore. What I'm asking is a complete explanation on why this code works and how it works. Why the semaphores are initialized with 0 permissions? Why there is sem_post(first_semaphore)? I'm very confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there's a bug in that code...

After it has done its job, each thread unconditionally calls `sem_post()` on the semaphore of the next thread. Therefore, the third thread will try to access `semaphores[3]` which doesn't exist.

Now what's going on (assuming the bug wasn't there) is this:

- 3 semaphores are created and initialized so that they are locked immediately
- 3 threads are created, each calling `sem_wait()` and blocking (because the semaphores are initialized to 0)
- After a thread has done it's job, it calls `sem_post()` on the semaphore of the next one, which then returns from `sem_wait()`

This is the basic idea, but to get it running, someone needs to call `sem_post()` for the first semaphore. So that's why there is that `sem_post(&semaphores[0])` in main().

Answer (score 1):

Note: This is more of a long comment, not a complete answer.

I like to think of a semaphore as a blocking queue of informationless tokens. The semaphore's *count* is the number of tokens in the queue.

From that viewpoint, the main thread in your program creates a single token (from nothing, because the token *is* nothing), and it hands the token to the first worker thread by calling `sem_post(&semaphores[0]);`.

The first worker is able to do its job after taking the token from its input queue (i.e., when `sem_wait(&semaphores[th_data->id]);` returns. And after it has finished its work, it hands the token to the next thread:  `sem_post(&semaphores[th_data->id + 1]);`